# Trying to get images from Reddit using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oauth, reddit

For this particular task, I have decided that it would be best if I were to use the Reddit API. Looking at the different wrappers available, I chose to use [snoowrap](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/snoowrap). The examples are pretty clear, and I want to use something like this to get through authentication:

```
const snoowrap = require('snoowrap');

const otherRequester = new snoowrap({
    userAgent: 'put your user-agent string here',
    clientId: 'put your client id here',
    clientSecret: 'put your client secret here',
    username: 'put your username here',
    password: 'put your password here'
});
```

I can find the important information such as `clientID` and `clientSecret` on the [Reddit Apps (Preferences Section)](https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps/). What confuses me, is the `userAgent` input. What exactly am I supposed to input here?

I thought I could go to [Reddit OAuth Helper](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/reddit-oauth-helper) created by the same user. However, at the end of the process, I seem to get a *Reddit Bad Request*.

Comment: For `userAgent` you're going to want to put a user-agent string there.

Comment: what exactly is my user-agent string and where can I find it? @SvenWritesCode

Comment: I really don't mean to be rude, but if you google "what exactly is my user-agent string" the first site titled `What's My User Agent? - User Agent & Browser Tools` tells you.

Comment: @SvenWritesCode yeah, I looked at that, But that's specific to my machine, I wanted it to work for all machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User agent is the browser where the request is being sent from:

you can use the following command to populate that data:

`navigator.userAgent`

**EDIT:**

The above will only work client side, on the server side if you're in a Nodejs(Expressjs) environment you can get the user agent from the headers data in the request parameter of your function executing your API call. Something like this:

```
app.get('/api-call', function(request, response){
    const snoowrap = require('snoowrap');

    const otherRequester = new snoowrap({
        userAgent: request.headers['user-agent'], 
        clientId: 'put your client id here',
        clientSecret: 'put your client secret here',
        username: 'put your username here',
        password: 'put your password here'
    });
    // rest of the code
});
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the error: `Error: Cannot find module 'navigator'`. What am I supposed to be doing here?

Comment: are you executing this function on the client or server side?

Comment: On the server side